# How do I inhibit suspend from the command line?

Tags: command-line, ssh, suspend

Is there a way to inhibit suspend/hibernate from the command line.  I want to ssh into my home computer and not have it suspend while I'm working on it.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is the remote machine running?

Comment: The remote machine is running Gnome on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Is it an Ubuntu Server or desktop install? Are you sure the ssh connection is not just dying? Trying enabling keepalive and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 4):

Use xdotool instead:

> sudo apt-get install xdotool

Then, in a bash loop like this

```
while true ; do
    DISPLAY=:0.0 xdotool key Shift_L   # send a "harmless" keypress to Xorg
    sleep 5                            # wait a little bit and do it again
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You also might want to try this script [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6wNE.png), it inhibits to suspend/turn off your machine, I use it when watching movies.

[image: img]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6wNE.png) http://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/movietime-stop-powersaving-to-watch-a-movie/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to disable power management in `gnome-control-center`.

Comment: Normally, I want my computer to suspend.  It's a laptop and all.  But when I ssh into it, I'd like suspend to be temporarily inhibited.

Comment: Hm, perhaps find out which gconf (or dconf, in this brave new 11.10 world) keys enable/disable suspend, then write a couple of shell scripts to change them to enable/disable suspend from the command line.